# Using sed on solaris to replace one line by two lines

Tags: sed, newline, solaris

I would like to replace all occurrences of `#include <string>` with `#include <string>` followed by `using namespace std;` on next line.
How can I do that using sed on Solaris for couple of files?

For example, say I have a couple of header files similar to as below:

```
....
#include <string>
....
```

I would like to replace all occurrences of `#include <string>` with `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`, as below:

```
....
#include <string>
using namespace std;
....
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Describe more precisely what you want to do and give an example input and desired output.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `xpg4` version of `sed` ahead of other versions on your PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed`, but if you want to used the older version, bear in mind that older `sed` is very particular about line breaks.  You probably need to use a literal newline in your sed command.  Try:

```
$ sed '/#include <string>/a\
using namespace std;
' input-file > output-file
```

Another option is:

```
$ echo using namespace std; > tmp-file
$ sed '/#include <string>/rtmp-file' input-file > output-file
```

Comment: second option: r requires a space after that

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '{print} /#include <string>/{print "using namespace std;"}' file
....
#include <string>
using namespace std;
....
```

The above will work on all awks on all systems except old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (an almost-POSIX awk) or nawk (an older, less fully functional awk).

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter - care to explain the downvote so I can improve my answer?

Comment: This answer cannot be improved(well, maybe `1; /#in....`, but that's just stylistic and one could reasonably argue that explicit `{print}` is superior).  It was probably someone who believes that using an appropriate tool is "wrong" if it isn't the specific tool asked about.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat some-file 
/* code code code */
#include <string>
/* code code code */

$ sed '/#include <string>/a using namespace std;' some-file 
/* code code code */
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/* code code code */
```

**Explanation:** `/#include <string>/` searches for "`#include <string>`", then the command `a` **a**ppends the string "`using namespace std;`".

See also [`man sed`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/sed-1.html#scrolltoc).

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/#include <string>/a\
using namespace std;
' file
```

Append after the newline of the match `a\` and add the string with a newline.